# Can't drive the nvidia GPU on Ubuntu server, finally Skipping registering GPU devices

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, tensorrt-python

I tried to run [a simple TensorFlow verify script](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/).

But always failed to drive my Nvidia GPU, always happened "Skipping registering GPU devices...". Finally, the script runs via CPU.

I expect to show as my MacBook: "Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.".

```
$ python verify.py 
2023-07-31 03:45:52.910362: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 AVX512F AVX512_VNNI FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-07-31 03:45:53.005472: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:104] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
2023-07-31 03:45:53.008241: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: :/usr/local/cuda-12.1/lib64
2023-07-31 03:45:53.008255: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2023-07-31 03:45:53.518928: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfer.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: :/usr/local/cuda-12.1/lib64
2023-07-31 03:45:53.518989: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfer_plugin.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: :/usr/local/cuda-12.1/lib64
2023-07-31 03:45:53.518996: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.
2023-07-31 03:45:54.609306: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: :/usr/local/cuda-12.1/lib64
2023-07-31 03:45:54.609364: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcublas.so.11'; dlerror: libcublas.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: :/usr/local/cuda-12.1/lib64
2023-07-31 03:45:54.609402: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcublasLt.so.11'; dlerror: libcublasLt.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: :/usr/local/cuda-12.1/lib64
2023-07-31 03:45:54.609442: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcufft.so.10'; dlerror: libcufft.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: :/usr/local/cuda-12.1/lib64
2023-07-31 03:45:54.635697: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcusparse.so.11'; dlerror: libcusparse.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: :/usr/local/cuda-12.1/lib64
2023-07-31 03:45:54.635815: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1934] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
2023-07-31 03:45:54.636048: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 AVX512F AVX512_VNNI FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
Epoch 1/5
```

---

I checked my environment below:

```
$ nvidia-smi
Mon Jul 31 04:01:02 2023       
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.54.03              Driver Version: 535.54.03    CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA A100-PCIE-40GB          Off | 00000000:5E:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   32C    P0              34W / 250W |   4598MiB / 40960MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |             Disabled |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  NVIDIA A100-PCIE-40GB          Off | 00000000:D8:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   33C    P0              33W / 250W |      7MiB / 40960MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |             Disabled |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A    215566      C   python3                                    1080MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A    335766      C   /usr/bin/python3                           1748MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A    346003      C   python3                                    1746MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

```
$ nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2023 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Feb__7_19:32:13_PST_2023
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.1, V12.1.66
Build cuda_12.1.r12.1/compiler.32415258_0
```

---

```
$ cat /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn_version.h | grep CUDNN_MAJOR -A 2
#define CUDNN_MAJOR 8
#define CUDNN_MINOR 9
#define CUDNN_PATCHLEVEL 2
--
#define CUDNN_VERSION (CUDNN_MAJOR * 1000 + CUDNN_MINOR * 100 + CUDNN_PATCHLEVEL)

/* cannot use constexpr here since this is a C-only file */
```

---

And already added below paths:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda-12.1/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-12.1/lib64
```

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#tested_build_configurations -- check the requirements for your Tensorflow version. You almost certainly do not have the correct CUDA version installed for whatever the version of Tensorflow requires.